# error with tomcat HTTP Status 404 The requested resource() is not available from eclipse but works from browser

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i am getting this error when i try to run jsp program from eclipse.

url http  ://localhost:8090/form1/META-INF/form.jsp

error with tomcat HTTP Status 404 The requested resource() is not available.

but when running same jsp program from browser http  ://localhost:8090/form1/form.jsp

it works.

using eclipse galileo ,tomcat6,ubuntu 11.10.
i have created my instance(user instance) of tomcat and there is tomcats webapps/WEB-INF directory, in webapps form.jsp file is there.

Answer (score 0):

the META-INF in the path appears to be your problem: http ://localhost:8090/form1/**META-INF**/form.jsp as opposed to the working http ://localhost:8090/form1/form.jsp